Showing that $G$ contains at least $M=\frac{{n\choose 6}}{2{{n-3}\choose 3}}$ monochromatic triangles
I want to show that a graph on $n\geq 6$ vertices contains either $M=\frac{{n\choose 6}}{2{{n-3}\choose 3}}$ cliques of size 3 or $M$ independent sets of size 3. I'm not sure how to proceed, I tried induction but I'm confused about my bounds. I have to use that $R(3,3)=6$. Any help would be appreciated!

Since $R(3,3)=6$, every subset of $V(G)$ of size $6$ has a subset $S$ of size $3$ inducing a clique or an independent set. Every such $S$ is in $\binom{n-3}{3}$ subsets on $6$ vertices, so there are
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{6}}{\binom{n-3}{3}}
$$
such sets $S$. At least half of them must induce either a clique or an independent set.
